# Angular Directive ng-click Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

*[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKp82YlmIs2tbuqXQFK7?p=preview)*

I have an external controller that contains a directive inside of its view.  The directive gets a list of process points and generates links where you can select each one.  It correctly sets up the HTML in the link function,  but the links' ng-click actions don't work.

Any ideas? :)

**Code for the Non-Plunkering**

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head><link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="widget">
      <process stages="production" at="productionAt"></process>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', ['app.directives', 'app.controllers']);

angular.module('app.controllers', [])
 .controller('widget', function($scope) {
    var selectStage = function () {
      alert(this.label + " selected.");
      $scope.processAt = this;
    }

    $scope.production = [
        {label: "Starting", select: selectStage}
      , {label: "Fermenting", select: selectStage}
      , {label: "Pouring",     select: selectStage}
      , {label: "Beer!",  select: selectStage}
    ];

    $scope.productionAt = $scope.production[0];
 });

angular.module('app.directives', [])
 .directive('process', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
      , replace: true
      , template: '<ol class="nav nav-pills"></ol>'
      , scope: {
            stages: "="
          , at: "="
        }
      , link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.stages.length; i++) {
            var $stage = $('<li ng-click="stages['+i+'].select()"><a>'+scope.stages[i].label+'</a></li>');
            if (scope.at == scope.stages[i]) {
              $stage.addClass('active');
            }
            $(element).append($stage);
          }
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try to create a function that returns the ng-click value. Maybe it has something to do with javascript closure (http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make `ng-click` directive work it needs to be processed('compiled') by angular infrastructure first, so instead of manually creating `li` elements in your directive about which angular doesn't have a clue they exist, you can use `ng-repeat` in directive template as follows (no need for manually creating DOM elements):

```js
angular.module('app.directives', [])
 .directive('process', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
      , replace: true
      , template: '<ol class="nav nav-pills"><li ng-class="{active: stage==at}" ng-click="stage.select()" ng-repeat="stage in stages"><a>{{stage.label}}</a></li></ol>'
      , scope: {
            stages: "="
          , at: "="
        }
    }
  });
```

Modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SW1Ph0nIjVYW3UzixtBx?p=preview

I think it's most elegant solution. Of course you can move template to eternal file and reference it via `templateUrl`.

Alternatively you could use `$compile` service on element after you added `li` items manually but it feels like a hack.

Comment: It is elegant, short and doesn't require jQuery. +1

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much.  I was definitely not doing things the 'angular way'.

Answer (score 2):

Working url http://plnkr.co/edit/3zuDuQDjhA5UY5nLD09Z?p=preview

Please make below change in url directive

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
 .directive('process', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
      , replace: true
      , template: '<ol class="nav nav-pills"></ol>'
      , scope: {
            stages: "="
          , at: "="
        }
      , link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.stages.length; i++) {
            var $stage = $('<li ng-click="stages['+i+'].select()"><a>'+scope.stages[i].label+'</a></li>');
            if (scope.at == scope.stages[i]) {
              $stage.addClass('active');
            }
            $(element).append($stage);
            $compile($(element))(scope);
          }
        }
    }
  });
```

i have injected $complie and added one line $compile($(element))(scope);